# Append a text from source to destination

Tags: sed, grep

I would like to know on appending a text from a source file along with text concatenation to a new destination file.

Answer (score 2):

Using `cat`:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 >combined-file
```

`cat` (short for "concatenate") will read each file given on the command line and concatenate them on its output.  You may redirect the concatenated output to a new file, as shown above.

This may also be done in steps (not commonly done, but it shows how to *append* contents from one file to another):

```
cat file1 >combined-file
cat file2 >>combined-file
cat file3 >>combined-file
```

The first command will create or truncate (empty) the file `combined-file`, while the last two commands will append to that file (`>>` vs. `>`).

To select only a few lines from one file and append these to another already existing file:

```
grep 'PATTERN' file1 >>file2
```

This would extract all lines from `file1` that matched the regular expression `PATTERN` and append them to the end of `file2`.